# Does AJAXify of create relationship link possible out of the box?

Tags: 7, ajax, users

I'm using [User Relationship](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_relationships) module. I've enabled:

- ur
- ur_ui
- ur_views

and added UR link to View. By default this link work with relationship confirmation form.

Any module/settings in UR to ajaxify this link?

Comment: I ajaxify UR functionality by creating custom flag to control relationship status (flag module)